# How to receive a large string back from a C++ DLL in VB6

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, vb6

I need to be able to return a value > 65535 characters from a Unicode C++ DLL.

In order to call a C++ DLL, I have my VB6 declaration as:

`Private Declare Function MyFunction Lib "mydll.dll" (ByVal uStringIncoming As String, ByVal uStringOut As String) As Long`

And I call the function with this code snippet:

```
Private Function sFunc(sIncoming as String) As String
    Dim uReturnString As String
    Dim uIncoming_Local As String
    Dim rv as Long
    uIncoming_Local = StrConv(sIncoming, vbUnicode)
    ' A fixed length string in VB6 is limited to 64KB in length (65535)
    uReturnString = String$(65535, vbNullChar)
    rv = MyFunction(uIncoming_Local, uReturnString)
    If (rv == 0) Then
        sFunc = StrConv(uReturnString, vbFromUnicode)
    End If
End Function
```

MyFunction can handle any size incoming string, but iIf the return string is > 65535 characters, the function crashes because the uReturnString is only 65535 chars long.

How do I get around this limitation?

Comment: What you show as `String$(65535, vbNullChar)` is not a fixed-length string. It's a variable-length string with a set size. Have you tried increasing it? What does the DLL function's prototype look like, before you translate it into your `Declare`?

Comment: Wow, how awful.  So much character re-encoding going on here.  Rewrite the C++ to handle BSTRs properly and use a type library, not `Declare`.

Comment: @Bob77 I know, right? Do you have example code of doing this?

Comment: @JimMack It won't go past 65535. Max limit in VB6. Here's the function in C++:  `LONG WINAPI MyFunction(CONST WCHAR *wStringIncoming, WCHAR *wOutString)`

Comment: VL strings are *not* limited to 64K in VB6. I can successfully do this: `dim g as string : g = string$(1234567, 65) : debug.print mid$(g, 123456, 1)`. Try it. But the code is quite a bodge. If you have control of the c++ dll, you should refactor it to deal with BSTR.

Comment: As already pointed out, VB6 hasn't a 64k limit for _dynamic_ strings, only for **fixed-lenght** string, i.e. `Dim s As String * 1024`. Just place your cursor on the string data type and press F1 for help: A **variable-length** string can contain up to approximately **2 billion (2^31) characters.**
A **fixed-length** string can contain 1 to approximately **64K (2^16) characters.**.